# pysftp connection change directory doesn't work

Tags: python, ssh, cd, pysftp

I've tried the following three ways to change a directory and it never changes. has anyone else had this problem?

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
host = 'server1.mydomain.com' # altered
with pysftp.Connection(host=host, **get_credentials(), cnopts=cnopts) as connection:

    connection.execute('cd project')
    print(connection.execute('pwd'))      #---> [b'/home/jm\n']

    connection.execute('cd /home/jm/project')
    print(connection.execute('pwd'))      #---> [b'/home/jm\n']

    connection.cd('project')
    print(connection.execute('pwd'))      #---> [b'/home/jm\n']

    with connection.cd('project'):
        print(connection.execute('pwd'))  #---> [b'/home/jm\n']
```

`'/home/jm/project/'` does exist by the way. I've also trid many other combinations that I didn't list here.

It doesn't make any sense to me, can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `chdir()` instead. Per the docs:

```
cd(remotepath=None)
context manager that can change to a optionally specified remote directory and restores the old pwd on exit.

chdir(remotepath)
change the current working directory on the remote
```

So:

```
connection.chdir('/home/jm/project')
```

Comment: In the end though, that didn't work either. maybe its a problem with pysftp talking to centos 7 or something. What did work was this: I have 
 to move to the directory and immediately execute my desired command. otherwise, it moves me back directly after this command finishes executing. `connection.execute('cd /home/jm/project ; ls')` In other words its as if there's no persistence of the current working directory change.

Comment: cd in this case is context aware, like documentation say: [link](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html#pysftp-cd). So it reverts to the original path when function ends.